# A question about order of an integral on the unit circle

Tags: analysis

Is it true that:$$\int_{1}^{N}e^{2\pi ibx^\alpha}dx=O(N^{1-\alpha})$$
where $N$ is apositive integer and $0\lt\alpha \lt 1$ is a real number and $b$ is a nonzero real number?Is it easy?!

Comment: Where is this problem from? What have you tried?

Comment: A problem in fourier analysis.